# Angular2 : add class on select if no value selected / remove if value

Tags: angular

I'm doing a combo select and I have to put a class on each select when a value is selected.

My component look like that :

```
    constructor() {

          this.select = {
              'ELEM1': ['VALUE1'],
              'ELEM2': ['VALUE1', 'VALUE2', 'VALUE3']
          };
      }

      ngOnInit() { }

      keys() : Array<string> {
          return Object.keys(this.select);
      }

      selectOnChange(value): void {
          this.subSelect = this.select[value];
      }
```

My html look like that :

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>
            <select [class.placeholder]="noValueSelected1" class="form-control" (change)="selectOnChange($event.target.value)">
                <option value="">Select1</option>
                <option *ngFor="let key of keys()" [attr.value]="key">{{ key }}</option>
            </select>
         </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>
            <select [class.placeholder]="noValueSelected2" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Select2</option>
                <option *ngFor="let item of ciaSubSelect" [attr.value]="item">{{ item }}</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ngClass to set css class.

Please check below code:

```
<select [ngClass]="{'yourCssclass':subSelect === ''}" class="form-control" (change)="selectOnChange($event.target.value)">
            <option value="">Select1</option>
            <option *ngFor="let key of keys()" [attr.value]="key">{{ key }}</option>
        </select>
```

Hope it helps!!